# Sobolev spaces doubt

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Can somebody help me with this doubt?

> Let $\Omega$ an open set and  $A$ be any finite subset of points of $\Omega.$
>   Is it true the following inequality?
>
> $\vert v(a) \vert \leq C \| v \|_p \quad \forall a \in A, \; \forall v \in H^p(\Omega).$
>
> ($\| \cdot \|_p$ denotes the usual Sobolev norm.)

Regards

Comment: It is preferable to use `\|` instead of `||` to get a norm symbol in LaTeX; the lines are closer together.

Answer (score 1):

The inequality holds if $H^p(\Omega) \subset C^\gamma(\Omega)$ for some $\gamma > 0$ (the $C^\gamma$-norm bounds all $v(a)$ since $A$ is bounded). That is the case for $p$ large enough (depending on the space dimension).

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_embedding (Morreys inequality) or https://mathoverflow.net/questions/25470/when-is-sobolev-space-a-subset-of-the-continuous-functions.

The rules given in the mathoverflow post are sharp, I believe, but I don't know any counterexamples.

Comment: The counterexamples are $|x|^{-\epsilon}$ and $\log\log|x|$ (the latter is needed in the borderline case).